# React redux firebase `profile` is not loaded

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase, redux, react-redux-firebase

Profile is not loaded.

Update profile is performed as:

```
firebase.updateProfile(cred)
```

Firebase data entry appears:

```
root
  \ null
      \ UnIqUeStRiNgIdEnTiFiEr
         | displayName: "Name"
         | email: "test@example.com"
         \ password: "pass"
```

After that profile is loaded and `displayName` is visible.

Now sign out and sign in again:

Login perfformed as:

```
firebase.login(creds).catch(err => showError(err.message))
```

redux state:

```
root
  \ firbase
      | profile
      |  | isLoaded: false
      |  \ isEmpty: true
      |
      \ auth
         | uid: "UnIqUeStRiNgIdEnTiFiEr"
         | displayName: null
         \ email: "test@example.com"
```

profile is not loaded and `displayName` is not visible.

What is wrong? What need to check? What need to kick to load profile?

Comment: In my case, if you're trying to use password-less login, it isn't documented react-redux-firebase. I had to use email and password in order for it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Redux store require a `firebase` middleware.

Firebase middleware creator `reactReduxFirebase(firebase, firebaseReduxConfig)` require a config for firebase profile storage. It must be like this:

```js
const firebaseReduxConfig = {
  userProfile: 'users', // root for user profiles
  // ...
}
```

In my case config was wrongly imported as `default` instead of `named`. Therefore profiles was saved to `null` root entry which is showed in question.